# Creating DataBase (mdf) from DataSet

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, dataset, mdf

I have a DataSet consistint of a big number of tables of information.
Is it possible automaticly create SQL Server DataBase (mdf-file) from description of my DataSet? 
Of course, I can do it manually, but may be there is a better way?

Comment: nothing automatic available, I'm afraid. You'd have to create a brand new database, and then loop through the dataset, inspect each table, create a database table from that, and then store the data into that new table. No magic bullet to automate this.... typically, users running an app don't have those rights to create database objects anyway, so that's another issue that might come up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a XSLT script that will create DDL statements from a DataSet xsd.  It's [here](http://www.annlewkowicz.com/2008/01/create-ddl-from-xsd-file-part-ii.html).  The database itself would have to be created, and you'd have to manually execute the SQL script the XSLT script created.  But if you have a complex enough DataSet with enough tables, it might be preferable to doing it all by hand.